# How to display a random class every hour based on real life time with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I looked everywhere I could think of, but since my knowledge of jQuery and Javascript is very little (I can only edit codes to match my wishes), I can't do it myself so I wondered if someone could help me. I think it is possible since I've seen similar codes.

I want to display a random class every time the real life hour changes (doesn't need to be automatic, I don't mind if it needs page refresh). I found this code, all I need is someone to help me adapt it so that it only happens once an hour. If possible I would like the interval to be modifiable so I could test it without waiting an hour x)

```
$('.meteo').each(function() {
var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
$(this).addClass("color-" + number.toString()); });
```

I saw that you prefer people to try something themselves, but I'm really not skilled enough for something like that.

Thanks for those who will help!

**UPDATE**:
I've been helped with it, but finally, I realized that the code is not like I hoped it would be : when I load the page, it starts from the beginning. What I mean is that I want the pages to look excatly the same for everyone who visits it, but still change randomly the classes once an hour. I think the code starts when the page is loaded, not when it's created. I hope I made myself clear, and that someone or those who already helped me will be able to help me find the solution. 
Knowledge in jQuery is needed as Flyer53 said.

```
// get current minute and save it in a variable
var h = new Date().getSeconds();

// start an interval (every 1000ms in this example)
window.setInterval(function(){
    // check current minute
    var hCurrent = new Date().getSeconds();
    // and compare it with saved minute
    if (h !== hCurrent) {
        // if current minute is not equal to saved minute do something and reset saved minute
        h = new Date().getSeconds();        
        // your code to generate a class etc. goes here
        $('.meteo').each(function() {
          var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
          $(this).removeClass().addClass("meteo color-" + number);
        });        
    }
},1000);
```

Comment: [`var hours = (new Date).getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is how you'd get the current hour. (It's 7:44am here and I get `7`). [You also have access to `setInterval` and `setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers)

Comment: Thanks for giving me this. I have no idea how to integrate it to my base code, could you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that might help you. It basically saves the current minute when the script is loaded. Then it starts an interval that runs every second in this case and checks whether the current minute is different to the saved one. If so -> do something. Since you want to look for a change of the hour you would have to replace the method .getMinutes() with .getHours(). I just used .getMinutes() so that you see something happen after a minute when you run the code snippet.

**UPDATE:**
Example now is complete with HTML and CSS.

```js
// get current minute and save it in a variable
var h = new Date().getSeconds();

// start an interval (every 1000ms in this example)
window.setInterval(function(){
    // check current minute
    var hCurrent = new Date().getSeconds();
    // and compare it with saved minute
    if (h !== hCurrent) {
        // if current minute is not equal to saved minute do something and reset saved minute
        h = new Date().getSeconds();        
        // your code to generate a class etc. goes here
        $('.meteo').each(function() {
          var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
          $(this).removeClass().addClass("meteo color-" + number);
        });        
    }
},1000);
```

```css
.meteo{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}
.color-1{background: red;}
.color-2{background: green;}
.color-3{background: blue;}
.color-4{background: grey;}
.color-5{background: yellow;}
.color-6{background: brown;}
.color-7{background: linen;}
.color-8{background: rebeccapurple;}
.color-9{background: orange;}
.color-10{background: olive;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="meteo color-1"></div>
<div class="meteo color-2"></div>
<div class="meteo color-3"></div>
<div class="meteo color-4"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I think I understand most of it, but I have a few questions : what will the html code look like and do I simply copy/paste my code where you say it should be?

Comment: @Azel Updated example with HTML and CSS. Note that you have to wait a minute when executing the code snippet. Also note the small change to your code sample: You don't need to convert the number to a string first when concatenating with a string. And I first remove the classes before adding the new one. And I used .getSeconds() instead of .getHours(), so you see the change every second executing the code snippet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I wanted. I tried to set getHours when it was 20:55 and then at 21h it did set the random classes. Have a good day and thanks again :)